# How can I detect suspicious reference comparisons in Java automatically?

Tags: java

Is there any way to check if a big project contains a reference comparison like `Integer == Integer` instead using the `equals` method?

I need to find those occurrences in a very big project.

Comment: @StefanBeike Using `==` in many cases is *probably* wrong, which is why many tools will warn about its use. Obviously if it were always wrong then the compiler wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @StefanBeike: comparing two `Integer` references using `==` is certainly a strong enough smell to warrant close inspection of every single instance of it happening, even in a big project. Yes, it *could* be valid code, but it's extremely unlikely to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) will do it. The specific check is [RC_REF_COMPARISON](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RC_REF_COMPARISON).

IntelliJ inspections also cover this.